# Outputting Multidimensional Array in View

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

I am currently working on a Laravel project and run the following query to build this multidimensional array:

Basically what I am trying to do is see the 5 different statuses and get the count of how many of those applications with a certain status are assigned to a certain admin.

The problem I am running into is outputting this data on my view. This is what I have so far:

I am getting an error saying undefined index first_name.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the output of var_dump($totalCounts);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you get undefined index is that you don't assign an exact index `first_name`.

Lets say the user's first name is `Burak`, status is `Something` and count is 5 within the line below.

```
$totalCount[$count->first_name][$count->status] = $count->count;
```

And actually you assign like below.

```
$totalCount['Burak']['Something'] = 5;
```

So if you want to access to it, then you need to reach to the first name within your view. To access them within your view :

```
@foreach ($totalCount as $name => $count)
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{$name}}
        <br>
        <a href="#">Closed</a>
      </td>
      @for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++)
           <td><a href="#">
           @foreach ($count as $status => $c)
                @if($i == $status)
                    {{ $c }}
                @endif
           @endforeach
           </a></td>
      @endfor
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: I see what you mean. If you look now, I have added the var_dump of my array. The thing is I have multiple first names, and each person has array of the status and the count which is status_count in your example. In my View I am trying to see how to iterate over this $totalCount and output that first name. Then if(status ==2) output status_count where status = 2 in the array. If that makes more sense

Comment: Hey Burak I am still having a problem. On my table, which I am outputting the data, it is not lining up meaning it does a new line for the name even though I want it to be all on one line. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/SP60SuPM

Comment: its because you have a <br> tag after `$name`. remove it, then you are fine.

Comment: but that is just in that table record, it should not be affecting the rest of table. I just have it there to put line between the name and closed link

Comment: you have your tags opened and closed in wrong places. actually you don't even need the if tags, if your code structure is like that. put the starting and closing `<td>` tags within `foreach` block. See this: http://pastebin.com/svFRNnNx actually, it should look like this: http://pastebin.com/90xjWMYP

Comment: Burak sorry for the confusion, but the output is still wacky. Here it is: http://prntscr.com/7kf1av And here is the code I am currently using: http://pastebin.com/jY14PdtV  The names are ouputting fine, I just did not include them in the screen grab

Comment: you just need to output once http://pastebin.com/hy3vxq9A, can you share the full code, that containts the `th` tags too?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/N9JEnr5U Here it is. Have not tried your code let me try. Ok just saw your code...yes sorry it must be confusing. I have many table headers, that represent a certain status. Example: Qualified Prospect is status 2, Unqualified is status 3...etc. And if you look at my array, some people have counts for one status or not, but it is not necessarily they all will have a count for every status. So I can put a blank, or zero there

Comment: your if else tags are wrong, you are not looking for empty or not, you just look whether the status is equal to some integer, otherwise you always output an extra `td` everytime, see this: http://pastebin.com/5iCBkn1j

Comment: wow thank you so much! But Burak one last question. Let me show you the screen grab: http://prntscr.com/7kfcml  It is still not properly formatted, even though it is a table and outputting correct info but just not in right spots. For example, on the second row, that 4th number 1 should be all the way down under Revenue Generating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81323/discussion-between-burak-and-milan-am).